# what happens when we include wrong attributes in html tags?

Tags: html, browser

I have noticed that the browser does not complain in any manner when I include non existing attribute names for html tags. for example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head test1="abc">
        <title test2="cba">My Sample Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Sample Project</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is actually happenning here? Does the html parser in the browser ignore attributes when it doesn't know what to do with it? I also found that the same behaviour is seen when we include non existing tags as well. Does it mean that the browser interprets the html it can understand and does not complain about anything else in the file?

Comment: For HTML, a browser just doesn't do anything 'special' with them, effectively ignoring unknown attributes. That is all. (They are still available as DOM attributes, which is relied upon by some JavaScript frameworks; also see `data-` attributes for a 'safer' alternative.)

Comment: The html parser doesn't care at all, and will parse pretty much anything. W3C and general standards, however, care quite a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can technically have any sort of attribute you want, and it will be accessible throughout html, css, and javascript.

Example:

```
<h1 id="heading" my-attribute="foo" another="bar">My Heading</h1>
```

CSS

```
h1[my-attribute=foo]{
   background:red;
}
```

Javascript

```
console.log(document.getElementById('heading').getAttribute('my-attribute');//logs "foo"
```

This technically works too:

```
<mytag>Something awesome.</mytag>
```

However, there is a reason we have a standards model (W3C). Do we want developers relearning all the tags they are going to be using in a project? Or figure out how to access certain attributes of those tags? It can get out of control quite quickly.

**How to do custom attributes**

With HTML5, now it's considered standard practice to use `data-` to create custom defined attributes:

```
<h1 data-alt="my alternate data">This is totally standard compliant</h1>
```

These are 100% valid, standard compliant custom attributes, you can read about them in depth at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

This allows for us to tag custom data and be sure that new browsers won't come along and stomp all over us with handling our attributes in odd ways (as Katana314 said in their more concise answer).

Comment: @Charlie Hm. Is there a reason my link to the MDN explanation of data attributes got edited out, but not Jesse's?

Answer (score 3):

Any slight upgrade to browsers would cause a lot of issues if the previous browsers just gave errors for all the things they didn't recognize. That said, the page will fail W3C validation; and making up attributes generally isn't recommended (What if, two years from now, `test1` is a valid HTML5 attribute that triggers a browser's unit-testing functions? Okay, a stretch.)

If you do want to make up attributes for random purposes, I would recommend you start them with [`data-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).